# No option for Azure NC/NV VMs?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to create a Windows 10 Pro VM on Azure using an NC/NV server in the correct regions here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/regions/services/ but don't find the option to select NC or NV even when looking at the correct regions.

Is this a limitation of the free trial?

Comment: free tier doesnt impose any limitations, as long as you have money. probably windows 10 is not suited for type of workloads Microsoft envisions for these vms

Comment: I wanted to use the VM for rendering so wanted a Windows 10 install to replicate my home computer.

It looks like it's not available for the free tier as in the US West 2 region it shows up as 'not available' with th einfo saying it's nota vailable at this current subscription level which is sad news for me I guess...

Comment: you might not have quota, that might be the thing, open up support request to allow you to provision nc\nv series vms. that's not a free account limitation, thats your azure subscription limitation. i have 3 subs, all of those have different quotas for different regions

Answer (score 2):

This is because your chose SSD disk type to create a VM. Try to change the disk type to HDD and then you can choose NC/NV Size .

You can see more details about this Deployment considerations in [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-gpu#deployment-considerations).

---

**Update**

Due to the OP - [@tweetypi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47324836/no-option-for-azure-nc-nv-vms/47325073#47325073) said, there is also another cause. You may be with the free tier and restricted to 4 V-CPUs ,but NV6  requires 6 CPUs.

Also said in that document:

> If you want to deploy more than a few N-series VMs, consider a
>   pay-as-you-go subscription or other purchase options. If you're using
>   an Azure free account, you can use only a limited number of Azure
>   compute cores.

Comment: ah unfortunately with the free tier it looks like I'm restricted to 4 V-CPUs and the lowest available option is an NV6 which requires 6, so I'm effectively locked out of nVidia VMs...